# How does one go about making a multiclass classifier for structured data using Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I've read Tensorflow's tutorial(https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/preprocessing_layers) for binary classification for structured data but I can't manage to modify it to produce a model that will be able to do a multiclass classification.

Answer (score 0):

first, you should add a Dense layer as the last layer that the numbers of a neuron are equal to the class numbers.
if each input can be members of more than one class you should use the sigmoid activation function for the last layer and binary_crossentropy loss function.
the reason is that in the softmax function sum of the all outputs is equal to 1. so it isn't good for multi-class. but when you use sigmoid, each class would be as a binary classification problem.
also if each input can be a member of only one class. you should use the softmax activation function and  categorical_crossentrop loss function.

Comment: by any chance, do you have a sample project where you implemented this?

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple project for the Reuters dataset with 46 class numbers and 10000 feature inputs. I used Keras but TensorFlow is the same.

```
from keras.datasets import reuters
from keras import models
from keras import layers
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



def binery_vectorize(sequences, dimension):
    results = np.zeros((len(sequences), dimension))
    for i, sequence in enumerate(sequences):
        results[i, sequence] = 1.
    return results

(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = reuters.load_data(num_words=10000)

word_index = reuters.get_word_index()
reverse_word_index = dict([(value, key) for (key, value) in word_index.items()])
decoded_newswire = ' '.join([reverse_word_index.get(i - 3, '(?)') for i in train_data[0]])

x_train = binery_vectorize(train_data,10000)
x_test = binery_vectorize(test_data,10000)
y_train = binery_vectorize(train_labels,46)
y_test = binery_vectorize(test_labels,46)
```

if the inputs can be in only one class the model would be like below

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(10000,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(46, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

if the inputs can be in more than one class the model would be like below

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(10000,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(46, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

In the end fit model

```
 x_val = x_train[:1000]
partial_x_train = x_train[1000:]
y_val = y_train[:1000]
partial_y_train = y_train[1000:]

history = model.fit(partial_x_train,partial_y_train,epochs=20,batch_size=512,validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```